# Facebook Login Button shows loading circle above the login button but no login happens

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to add `Facebook Login button` to my Android App. 
I followed this tutorial https://github.com/slidenerd/FaceBookv4.0HelloWorld

Now, when I click on the login button, nothing happens.

The error I get in the logcat is:

```
E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.orca.notify.MessengerLoggedInUserProvider
```

Comment: change to add your app id in res/fb_app_id.xml??

Comment: I have already created APP id and generated Hash key for my app @sasikumar

Comment: this link may be helpful: https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/08/19/facebook-integration-in-android/#more-109

Comment: @Aakash It was very useful the tutorial you suggested. Add it as an answer to this question so I can accept it.

Comment: Try this link, this may be helpful: https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/08/19/facebook-integration-in-android/#more-109